# Google Code Prettify doesnt syntax highlight on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-code-prettify

I use Google Code Prettify to syntax highlight my code. This is my HTML

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id ="xmlView">
            <pre  class="prettyprint">
                <code class="language-xml" id="xmlTextArea"></code>
            </pre>
        </div>
</body>
```

When adding Code directly in HTML to xmlTextArea and replacing all < and > with > and < it does it's job, but not when setting the code with jquery like this:

```
$('#xmlTextArea').text(code)
```

I also tried to call `PR.prettyPrint()` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pretty code. You can refer to [code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) for more examples:

```js
var someCode = 'class Voila {public:static const string VOILA = "Voila";<a href="#voila2">tags</a>.}';
$('.prettyprint').html(someCode);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="xmlView">
    <pre class="prettyprint"></pre>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As I said, doing it like that works, but not when adding the code via jquery

Comment: Added the same via JQuery, it works except for the formatting which can be taken care.